What search algorithm is this?
My professor gave me some pseudocode and we have to figure out wheter the algorithm is cost - optimal or not. Its a modified version of the Best-First-Search with the difference that the algorithm tests wheter or not its a goal state right after the node is expanded.
Since it's given that f = g I figured it must be the Uniform-Cost-Search, but here the goal state is only tested after the expanded path is taken out of the priority queue? And since it has an priority queue at all i figured it can't be Breadth-First-Search either.
I personally think it must be the UCS but I can't really figure out if optimality would change wheter the goal state is tested right after the creation of the node or not. :/

So you want to know something different (name) than was asked by the professor (optimality)?
